# Как проверить, есть в ли в строке спецсимволы? (питон)

Tags: python

Нужно проверить, есть ли в строке спецсимволы (.,:;!_*-+()/#¤%&).
Например, есть ли в строке "Booster!" хоть один спецсимвол из списка выше.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы узнать пересекаются ли наборы символов:

```
>>> not set(".,:;!_*-+()/#¤%&)").isdisjoint("Booster!")
True
```

[`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint)  выясняет являются ли наборы несвязанными.

Можно регулярные выражения использовать:

```
>>> import re
>>> has_special = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, ".,:;!_*-+()/#¤%&)"))).search
>>> bool(has_special("Booster!"))
True
```

Или простой цикл (квадратичный алгоритм):

```
>>> text = "Booster!"
>>> any(char in ".,:;!_*-+()/#¤%&)" for char in text)
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Более общий случай:

```
import string
print string.punctuation #выводит !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~
```

далее через replace() можно удалить то что не нужно

Получение именно этих спецсимволов:

```
s = ".,:;!_*-+()/#¤%&"
my_string="Booster!"
set(s)&set(s1) # выведет общие символы, то есть !
len(set(s)&set(s1))>0 # выведет True

s = ".,:;!_*-+()/#¤%&"
my_string="Booster!"
any(x for x in s if x in my_string) # выведет True, если есть общие спецсимволы.
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать конструкцию if x in y: Вот так, например:

```
def strng(word):
 s = ".,:;!_*-+()/#%&"
 for char in s:
   if char in word:
        print "The character " +  char + " is in the word."
   else: pass

strng("Boost!")
```