# Снова привет всем, возник вопрос, нужно чтобы переменная проверялась на знаки

Tags: python

Снова привет всем, возник вопрос, нужно чтобы переменная проверялась на математические операторы (+, -, *, /) то есть если она содержит математический оператор, то выполняется код
А если не содержит: то пишет: ошибка, укажите действие
Помогите пожалуйста, кто знает как

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как проверить, есть в ли в строке спецсимволы? (питон)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762175/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd)

Comment: Два сета пересечь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```py
s = input()

if any(c in s for c in '+-/*'):
    print('Всё OK')
else:
    print('Ошибка')
```

Comment: Попробую спасибо

Comment: Спасибо, однако работает, очень благодарен вам